# Yii2 get insert query before saving model

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

**Yii2 Question:** Is there any way to get the current `insert` query before executing save? for instance `$model->save()`. For the current situation, save is actually inserting a row in a table.
I know about executing `function beforeSave($insert)` but this $insert only refers whether the event is valid or not, and does extra computation before saving in database.
Misc stuff: Find query can be printed as `$FindResultVariable->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql;` If someone can think in this direction too for solution?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Is it for debugging?

Comment: If you have [yii2-debug](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug) enabled, you can click the DB section and see all queries executed on the selected page. You can switch pages with the "Last 10" dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: i know about debugging stuff and it is enabled. The issue is with a weird case occurring on specific column. Same function is called for create and update - even the `$this->attributes` is same printing values on beforeSave(). And the Insert query on yii debug log has value of that column. But value is not saving for create. P.S: debug insert printed query has a value for that column. I can share screen shots if u want.

Comment: Check length of that field. If you're passing long data to the field which has small allowed storage that this can happen. e.g. you have varchar(50) field and you're passing data more than 50. also try $model->getErrors(); after model save method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model->insert();
```

This inserts the values before save.